# Jenkins groovy script, communication

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two groovy scripts in Jenkins server
i want to communicate these two groovy scripts
could you please help me out to this
How to communicated two groovy scripts with each other in Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Storing groovy script in Jenkins is not a good approach.
I would suggest you to use jenkinsfile or wrapper approach where you can commit you code into git and use it like function in script . you can also call one script into another.